# Class hierarchy - class should only called by another class

Tags: swift, class, security, hierarchy

I try to implement a `Security` class and a `Secret` class. In my whole project the `Secret` class should only called by `Security.getSecretInstance().doSomeSecretAction()`

So `Secret.doSomeSecretAction()` should throw an compile error.

I need the `Security.getSecretInstance()` for an authentication process.

I'm searching for a good pattern or something else, but I think my searching keywords are too bad or my requirement is stupid/or not possible.

At the moment I call `Security.getSecretInstance()` it returns a singleton instance of `Secret`, but I could call `Secret.doSomeSecretAction()` too. There is no difference.

Do you have some pattern, keywords or snippets for me?

**Edit**
My definition of awesome would be that I have one method like this:

```
Security.isAuthorized { secret in
   secret.doSomeSecretAction
 }, failure { 
   print("permission denied")
}
```

And I can get secret only with this `.isAuthorized`-Method

Comment: There are definitely ways to implement (roughly) what you're describing here (`doSomeSecretAction()` should not be a class method, but other than that it's fine). But I want to be clear: you want this in order to prevent developers accidentally calling `.doSomeSecretAction` when they shouldn't, not to stop someone with access to your framework who intends to extract the secret, correct? The former is fairly straightforward. The latter is impossible. There is no way to hide anything in Secret that a developer cannot extract. This isn't a Swift limitation. It can't be done in any language.

Comment: You understand me completely right: Yes, I want this in order to prevent developers accidentally calling `.doSomeSecretAction` when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I find a good and simple solution for me:

```
class SecurityLayer {

private static var authorized: Bool = false

static func makeAuthorizeCheck() -> API2? {
    if authorized {
        return API2()
    }
    return nil
   }
}
```

Second class (not subclass)

```
class Secret {

  func test() {
    print("test")
  }

  fileprivate init() {

  }
}
```

Examples

```
  SecurityLayer.makeAuthorizeCheck()?.test() //working
  Secret() //forbidden
  Secret.test() //compiler find this method, but there are no permissions to use this one
```

When the constructor inside `Secret` is `private` this wouldn't work anymore. For me the benefit of `fileprivate` is obvious now. 
!The classes have to be in one file!

Answer (score 3):

What I would recommend doing is declare `Secret` nested inside `Security`, make `Secret` private and create non-private methods inside `Security` that can access `Secret`. Something like this:

```
class Security {

    class func doSomeSecretAction() {
        Secret.doSomeSecretAction()
    }

    private class Secret {
        class func doSomeSecretAction(){
            print("Private method called")
        }
    }
}

Security.doSomeSecretAction()
```

Here, `Security.doSomeSecretAction()` can be called from outside the `Security` class, but `Secret.doSomeSecretAction()` can only be called inside the `Security` class.

**Update based on comments:**
A feasible solution would be declaring the initializer of `Security` private, so it can only be called from inside the `Security` class and declaring a computed variable (for now I called it `shared`) which is the only access point to the initializer. This computed variable either returns `nil` or a new instance of the `Secret` class based on `Security.isAuthorized`. This way, every time a function of `Secret` is called, the authorisation status is checked and the function can only be called if the status is authorised, otherwise the `shared` variable returns `nil` and hence the method is not called.

```
class Security {

    static var isAuthorized = false //change this when the authorisation status changes

    class Secret {

        static var shared: Secret? {
            if Security.isAuthorized {
                return Secret()
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }

        private init(){} //a new instance of Secret can only be created using the `shared` computed variable, the initializer cannot be called directly from outside the Secret class

        func doSomeSecretAction(){
            print("Private method called")
        }
    }
}

Security.Secret.shared //nil
//Security.Secret.init() //if you uncomment this line, you'll get an error saying all initializers are inaccessible
Security.Secret.shared?.doSomeSecretAction() //nil

Security.isAuthorized = true
Security.Secret.shared?.doSomeSecretAction() //function is called

Security.isAuthorized = false
Security.Secret.shared?.doSomeSecretAction() //nil
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not convinced. My Secret class has 500 lines of code and a lot of methods. With your pattern/method I duplicate the code. It is okay, but I was hoping there is a more elegant pattern.

Comment: Why would you duplicate that code? You still only write that code inside the `Secret` class, you only need to make helper functions for the ones that you want to be able to use from outside `Security` as well. Moreover, it doesn't matter, how long a function internally is inside `Secret`, the helper function only needs a single line, in which you call the private function from `Secret`.

Comment: What you were trying to do, `Security.getSecretInstance().doSomeSecretAction()` to work, but `Secret.doSomeSecretAction()` to be non-callable cannot work, since you cannot ensure that a function can only be called from inside an another function if the function itself is visible to an outer scope. You can only ensure this by declaring he function or the whole class with a restricted access and creating helper functions that can access it directly.

Comment: For every method in `Secret` I need to write 3 lines of code in Security or not? 
Before I'm allowed to call the methods in Secret there is a sometimes async authentication check. So with every method I will get redundant code.   

My definition of awesome would be that I have one method like this: 
 `Security.isAuthorized { secret
    secret.doSomeSecretAction
 }, failure {
    print("permission denied")
 }`

And I can get secret only with this `.isAuthorized`methods

Comment: What you just described in your comment is very different than what you asked in your question. What you ask in your question is not possible, since as soon as you return the singleton instance of `Secret` outside the scope of the `Security` class, you cannot declare it private anymore and hence it can be accessed from anywhere outside the `Security` class as well.

Comment: However, if you only want the functions of `Secret` to be available if `Security.isAuthorized` returned true, you can just use a boolean variable storing the authorisation state and only allow instantiation of the `Secret` class if the state is authorised. Is this `isAuthorized` function only called once per app launch or can the authorization status change later on in the apps lifecycle as well?

Comment: For the secret you need a time limited token. So you the authorization status can change every time. Maybe a boolean could suffice.

Comment: @kuzdu check my updated answer based on our discussion in comments and see if it what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

*I was working on this answer while Dávid was editing his; I didn't realize he'd posted an update awhile ago. There's a lot of overlap in our answers, so this is just another style of the same approach.*

First, I want to be clear that what you're describing can only implement encapsulation, not "security." I mean that you can build a system that makes it easy for developers to use it correctly and difficult to use it incorrectly. That's pretty straightforward. But you won't be able to stop a developer from extracting the secret and running any code they want. It's their machine and you're giving them the code. They can always run it. They have a debugger; you're not going to hide anything.

But, preventing accidental misuse is a fine goal, and pretty straightforward. The first thing is that you should work with instance methods, not class methods. Class methods makes all of this harder than it needs to be. A solution to your problem will look something like this, relying on `fileprivate` for most of the access control.

```
class Security {
    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case unauthorized
    }

    // This feels like it should be nested in Security, but doesn't have to be
    class Secret {
        // No one outside this file can instantiate one of these. It's likely
        // that you'll be passing some parameters here of course.
        fileprivate init() {}

        // I'm assuming you want these to be single use, so people can't store
        // a reference to them an reuse them. This is one simple way. 
        fileprivate var isAuthorized = true

        private func validate() {
            // I'm treating this kind of reuse as a programming error and
            // crashing. You could throw if you wanted, but it feels like it
            // should never happen given your design.
            guard isAuthorized else { 
                fatalError("Secrets can only be used once") 
            }
        }

        func doSomeSecretAction() {
            // Every "protected" method (which may be all of them) needs to
            // call validate() before running.
            validate()
            print("SECRET!")
        }
    }

    // Public so we can test; obviously this would at least private(set)
    var isAuthorized = false 

    func withAuthorization(execute: (Secret) -> Void) throws {
        guard isAuthorized else { throw Error.unauthorized }

        // We create a new Secret for every access and invalidate it after.
        // That prevents them from being stored and reused.
        let secret = Secret()
        execute(secret)
        secret.isAuthorized = false
    }
}

// -- Some other file

let security = Security()

security.isAuthorized = true // For testing

var stealingTheSecret: Security.Secret?

do {
    try security.withAuthorization {
        $0.doSomeSecretAction() // This is good
        stealingTheSecret = $0 // Try to steal it for later use
    }
} catch Security.Error.unauthorized {
    print("Unauthorized")
}

stealingTheSecret?.doSomeSecretAction() // Let's use it: Crash!
```

In principle you could get rid of the `validate()` boilerplate by allocating the memory for `Secret` directly with `UnsafeMutablePointer` and destroying it at the end, but this is probably more trouble than it's worth to avoid one extra line of code.

(Note that allocating the memory yourself still wouldn't protect you against the caller saving the object; they can always make a copy of the memory and re-instantiate it with `.load`; any unsafe thing you can do, so can the caller. This also allows them to circumvent `validate()` by directly modifying the boolean or copying the object before you invalidate it. There is no technique that will prevent unsafe memory access; this is why you cannot protect secrets inside code.)